# Duplicate selected text to a new line VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already found that the `"command": "editor.action.duplicateSelection"`
will duplicate the selection right next to it.

I want to duplicate the selected text to a new line.  The selection may not be the entire line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a selection that is less than the entire line, there is no built-in way to duplicate selected text to the next line.  It can be done with the `runCommands` command which enables you to run multiple commands at once, i.e., no extension is needed.

Try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+i",                        // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
    "commands": [
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
  
        {                        // to add text after the selection
          "command": "type",     // you could also put this before the paste command
          "args": { "text": " myText here after paste " }
        }
  
      ]
    }
  }
```

That will copy the selected text, insert a blank line after it and paste that text there.  Demo:

[image: copy selection down]

Demo with adding static text to the duplicated text:

[image: copy selection down with static text]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked perfectly.

Can you please give an addtional information? Can i add an extra text (a static text) with the selection text when duplicating the text.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure exactly what you mean?  I'll edit the answer to show adding some text after the pasted selection.

Comment: You got me right. Great and appreciat you for your help.

One more thing to go. This time it add after the selection text. How can i add  static text before and after the selected text at the same time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured it out from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Click **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts:**
Look for the **Copy Line Down** keyboard shortcut.
[image]

Comment: The solution you have given, it copied the whole line, not the specific string i have selected with cursor.

However @Mark given the perfect solution.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer that the selected text may not be the entire line.

Comment: Thanks for edition. Your edited version is more clearer.